# How to remove icons from the Games folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons, libraries

I am one of these OCD nut jobs that likes to have all their game icons perfect in their "Games" folder in Windows 7.

However when I installed Far Cry 2 it made a "Default application" icon in the games folder and I cannot remove or delete it.

The game launches from it, so is there a way to at least give it an icon of some sort?

[image]

Comment: I really love these kinds of OCDs — I feel you.

Comment: I love messing with them as a systems admin.

Comment: Well then would you kindly enlighten us with your sys admin skillz? plzkthx

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1:

1. Please go to Start -> All Programs -> Games.
2. Right click the game you would like to change the icon and then click "Properties".
3. On Shortcut tab, click "Change Icon…" button.
4. Point to the location for the icon you would like to use.
5. Click OK twice.

In addition, we can edit the registry key value to change the game icons as well.

## Method 2:

1. Go to Start -> type regedit.exe in Search box -> right click regedit.exe and then click "Run as administrator".
2. Expand to the following registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameUX\Games

3. Double click the game's GUID (such as {00D8862B-6453-4957-A821-3D98D74C76BE}).
4. Double click ConfigGDFBinaryPath on the right pane.
5. Change the value of ConfigGDFBinaryPath to the new location of the icon file.
6. Click OK.

[Source of OCD Information](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/de9f5e2a-f627-434c-a871-1bb6ba6369ea)